# Cannot Connect to Redis Enterprise Cloud (gcloud)

Tags: redis, cloud, gcloud, enterprise

I have a Google Enterprise Subscription ( Redis Cloud/Fixed Plan/GCP/us-east1/Standard/100MB)

I can connect to the database from my local DEVELOPMENT environment.

BUT I CANNOT connect when I publish the app to the Google Cloud Platform (Cloud Run)

My Cloud Run app is in the same region as the Redis Instance (east-1)

Answer (score 0):

The connection between your GCP project and the Redis instance is achieved through a VPC network peering as specified on the [docs](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rc/security/database-security/network-security/#virtual-private-clouds). Check all the restrictions and considerations for [VPC network peering in GCP here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering). So I believe that if you make sure to [route all traffic from your service through a Serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#egress) that is paired with the VPC network peering associated with your Redis instance could do the trick.

Anyhow, assigning your Cloud Run service a static outboud IP address by following [this section of the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) should also guarantee that the connection is achieved. Notice that you'll basically need to configure the Cloud Run service's VPC egress to route all outbound traffic through a VPC network (using a [Serveless VPC Access connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#create-connector)) that has a Cloud NAT gateway configured with the static IP address. Making sure that this IP address is cleared under the [Source IP ACL](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rc/faqs/) related to your Redis Enterprise instance should guarantee the connection.

Finally, if you face too much difficulties achieving such a connection you could try to host your Redis instance in Cloud Memorystore and follow this section of the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run) (notice that you'll basically need to once again create a VPC connector).